É possível remover o atributo "readonly" de um tipo em TypeScript?
Como exemplo, teremos o tipo base User, já definido e o qual eu não posso alterar, abaixo:
type User = {
  readonly name: string
  readonly age: number,
  readonly role: string
}

Eu preciso desse tipo em um a nova interface que indique que a nova estrutura seja mutável, ou seja, não pode estar anotada como readonly, e tenho que me basear em tipagens já existentes. Claro que poderia fazer algo na mão, como:
type UserWithoutReadonly = {
  name: string
  age: number,
  role: string
}

Mas estou pensando em criar um tipo utilitário para não ter que reescrever manualmente e gerar muita duplicação de código.
Existe um tipo utilitário chamado Readonly<T> que adiciona o readonly aos campos, porém não encontrei um que faça o caminho inverso, de remover o readonly desses campos.
Seria possível criar um tipo utilitário customizado que me permita criar um UserWithoutReadonly  e que, de alguma forma, remova o readonly do tipo ReadonlyUser?
type User = {
  readonly name: string
  readonly age: number,
  readonly role: string
}
type UserWithoutReadonly = RemoveReadonlyDeAlgumJeito<User > // ?  


Se você remover o readonly você basicamente terá a classe User novamente, então basta fazer type WithoutReadonlyUser = User, se é que isso faz sentido. Por definição, o resultado de uma função inversa aplicada ao resultado da própria função será sempre o próprio argumento. f(g(x)) = x quando f é inversa de g.
